# Unabled to edit - Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a simple rest api

Right now the result from groups is this:

My result from devices right now

```
[
    {
        "id": "8079bf12-bb58-4ea0-a810-58a223d84be7",
        "name": "Cozinha"
    }
]
```

my models.py

```
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models

class Options(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Groups(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Devices(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Options)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

viewsets

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from devices.api import serializers
from devices import models

class DevicesViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.DevicesSerializer
    queryset = models.Devices.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
    
class OptionsViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.OptionsSerializer
    queryset = models.Options.objects.all()

class GroupsViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupsSerializer
    queryset = models.Groups.objects.all()
```

serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from devices import models


class OptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Options
        fields = '__all__'

class GroupsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Groups
        fields = '__all__'

class DevicesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupsSerializer()
    options = OptionsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Devices
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        group_data = validated_data.pop('group')
        options_data = validated_data.pop('options')
        group, _ = models.Groups.objects.get_or_create(**group_data)
        options = [models.Options.objects.create(**option_data) for option_data in options_data]
        device = models.Devices.objects.create(group=group, **validated_data)
        device.options.set(options)
        return device
```

I send a POST to "http://localhost:8000/groups/" to edit the group

```
 {
        "id": "8079bf12-bb58-4ea0-a810-58a223d84be7",
        "name": "Cozinha 123"
 }
```

But this create a new item in table insted of edit the line with this id, i know i need to add something to the serializers, but i'm to noob yet, i'm learning yet

**I try some solutions from internet but none with success, so can someone help me?**

Comment: Why you use post instead path or put?

Comment: yesterday before some modifications the post work like i pretent, and i dont know how to allow put 

Comment: @BrownBear Did you mean `patch`?

Comment: @SunderamDubey yesw sorry it was a typo `patch` or `put`

Comment: @BrownBear Ya I knew that, I clarified since if anybody (basically new guy who doesn't know about request methods) see it in future, so won't get confused ;)

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

The simple answer is that rather then calling **POST method**, You can call PATCH or PUT to update the Groups model. The reason is not exactly POST method itself but how viewsets handle POST, PUT and PATCH.

### Detailed Answer

The reason a new entity is being created is not because you are using the **POST method**, its actually because of how generic view sets handle the POST method.

if you look at the [source code for CreateModelMixin](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/b7523f4b9f5ec354cd50bd514784e6248be47a37/rest_framework/mixins.py#L14:%7E:text=serializer%20%3D%20self.get_serializer(data%3Drequest.data)). We can see that  during the serializier initialization only the request data is passed to it. So when the serializer calls its **save method** it does not have any idea if that instance already exists or not, [link for reference](https://Calling%20.save()%20will%20either%20create%20a%20new%20instance,%20or%20update%20an%20existing%20instance,%20depending%20on%20if%20an%20existing%20instance%20was%20passed%20when%20instantiating%20the%20serializer%20class:) and the viewsets use this create function to handle post requests.

if you look at the [source code of UpdateModelMixin](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/b7523f4b9f5ec354cd50bd514784e6248be47a37/rest_framework/mixins.py#L14:%7E:text=serializer%20%3D%20self.get_serializer(instance%2C%20data%3Drequest.data%2C%20partial%3Dpartial)), you will see that the instance (which is being updated) is also passed during serializer initialization. This `update` funtion is called during PATCH and PUT.

if you are deadest on using post to update your models (which you should not) You can always

- Update the save method of your model.
- Create your own custom viewset

Comment: Thanks, but i can't do a solution yet, can you help me code that in my example? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, Sure. The simplest solution for you is to send a PUT or PATCH request and Not a post request. If you are using Postman for sending request you an change the request type from the button just left of the url.